# Run a Cygwin shell (cygwin.exe) from a JAVA programme and write command line

Tags: java, windows, shell, cygwin

I am working on windows 7 and I need to run the cygwin shell from a java programm and to write command line from my programm
I have tried it with this:

```
             String[] mkdir1 = {"export PATH=$PATH:C:\\cygwin64\\bin"};
             Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
             Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe", mkdir1);
```

But it just opens a cygwin shell instead of running it and write the command in the mkdir variable.

I don't know what is the error there

Comment: try to pass a path to a script file insted of a command

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-319735.html), it's a real pain also to use bash from java, so through mintty ...
Maybe, you could launch directly bash with a script as argument `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/cygdrive/e/scripts/start.sh"`.
Try :

```
             String[] mkdir1 = {"-l -c \"/cygdrive/e/scripts/start.sh\""};    
             Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();    
             Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe", mkdir1);
```